# Flutter + iOS: Issues with multiple flavors. Taking wrong developer account for my configuration from Android Studio

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter app with multiple flavors. Also I have multiple developer accounts for different clients added to xcode.
Each flavor picks up a different apple developer account.

When I try to run the app from Android Studio for a particular flavor, it picks ups wrong developer account and gives me an error. But when I try to run from Xcode, it builds and runs successfully.

I need help to run the app directly from Android Studio as this will help me make the changes abd view it instantly on my ios device.
I even tried this with Visual Studio but getting that same error.

> Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error
> (Xcode): Failed to register bundle identifier: The app identifier
> "com.myappname" cannot be registered to your development team because
> it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string
> to try again.
> /Users/Documents/FlutterGitProjects/MyAppName/ios/Runner.xcodeproj
>
> Error (Xcode): No profiles for 'com.myappname' were found: Xcode
> couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching
> 'com.bookitngo'.
> /Users/Documents/FlutterGitProjects/MyAppName/ios/Runner.xcodeproj